# C++ bool array returns values other than 1 or 0

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

I have a really strange problem with my bool array. I have 3D bool array:

```
bool tab[wordLength][wordLength][nl];
```

I fill it with 0's and these are the only actions I do on that array later (in couple of for loops):

```
(...)
tab[1][s][v] = true;
```

and

```
(...)
if(tab[p-1][s-1][b] == true && tab[l-p-1][s+p-1][c] == true){
    tab[l-1][s-1][a] = true;
}
```

The problem is, when I want to write contents of that array in some cells I get 1 or 0 (as it should be) but in some I get numbers that are integers, for example 182 - how is that possible when it's bool array and I can only make it true or false?

Comment: is this tab array cleanly initialized, manipulated?

Comment: Can you please try  to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? What is `wordLenght`? What is `nl`? Can you show the actual initialization? The actual use of `tab`?

Comment: That is not a [mcve].  We have no idea what is going on behind those `...`.  Describing in words what you're doing is not the same as actually giving us an example that can be run and tested by everyone.

Comment: Yea, here's the problem - I can't. The thing I'm making is for school assignment and I fear that some of my collegues might be lurking on SO for answers for that task. If you can't answer my question with this amount of information I'll delete it.
`wordLength` is length of the string passed to the function, `nl` is length of a global string.
`bool tab[wordLength][wordLength][nl];` - this is the initialization and then using triple for loop I go trough every cell and set it to 0. For manipulation, well, only operations I do on that array are listed in the question.

Comment: If `wordLength` is a variable, then your `bool` array is not legal C++.  C++ arrays must be declared using constant values to denote the number of entries, not a variable.  So right there, you're off on the wrong foot.

Comment: Initialise with `bool tab[wordLength][wordLength][nl] = {};`. Don't write loops when you can avoid it.

Comment: @ard_evon [Does not compile](http://rextester.com/VTSO32321).  So if it is a school assignment, you are risking getting points taken off for using non-standard / invalid C++.

Comment: @ard_evon [Does compile](http://rextester.com/TKBAA98340).  C++ has no "variable length arrays", unless you use `std::vector`, some sort of container class, or (least recommended) use dynamic allocation using `new[ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

try this or you can use memset as sailfish009 suggest,

bool tab[wordLength][wordLength][nl] = {{{0}}};

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize 3d bool array.

```
memset(tab, 0, sizeof(bool)*wordLength*wordLength*nl);
```